Alternate to data fetching through DB Link stored procedures when migration to Oracle cloud database
What are the best alternate approach to data fetching through DB Link stored procedures when migration to Oracle cloud database. Currently our reconciliation application is fetching data from oracle database by calling oracle stored procedures using DB Link from recon application to core database. Now we are planning to move to Oracle cloud database, so we need to avoid direct DB Link approach. What will be the best alternate data fetching approach for this use case?
We are planning to move to Oracle cloud database architecture, so we need to avoid direct DB Links approach for fetching data from oracle database.

You could build rest endpoints on top of those procedures and consume those over https - that is a pretty common architecture.

@KoenLostrie I was concerned about REST API handling capability for number of records that could reach in millions.

Oracle APEX has some rest synchronization capabilities (that is a no cost option in the database) - you could also tag "oracle-rest-data-services" in this post, I can't add that tag without removing one and I'm not sure which ones you'd want to keep. Alternatively, check https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community - this sounds like a very common question. Oracle has some native tools too (https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/data-integration-platform-cloud/index.html)

@KoenLostrie ok I have added the tag oracle-rest-data-services
